# Does job intent service is always started in same background thread?

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer

I am very confused. Does job intent service is always started in same background thread?

I want to create audio media player in  notification. 
1) I want to send first notification, and play some music in this notification.
2) And I also want to send second notification and play another music in this notification.

When i send only one notification it works perfect.
But, when I send second notification and i click play button job intent service continues play old song in background.

Answer (score 1):

> Does job intent service is always started in same background thread?

No. The thread used for one `onHandleWork()` call may be completely different from the next `onHandleWork()` call. It might be a completely separate *process*, depending on what else is going on with the app and the device.

> job intent service continues play old song in background

A `JobIntentService` should not be doing things that continue after `onHandleWork()` completes. `JobIntentService` is designed for transactional bits of background work. For ongoing background work, such as playing music, use a foreground `Service`.